# updating the selection model and proxy model after insertion into a custom model in qt

Tags: qt

I have a model in which i will be adding symbols dynamically.
I am using a proxy model and a selection model for linking with the view
Every time i add a symbol to my source model the proxy model gets updated but the selection model i set for the view gets screwed up.
It doesn't recognize any selections anymore
can someone tell me why ??

```
void SymbolViewer::on_openButton_clicked()
{
    this->selModel = ui->symbolListView->selectionModel();
     ...
}
```

i set the selection model each time my i click a button to work on the selection.

Answer (score 1):

Im sure you re trying to access your model data with the indexes given by the selection model. But selection model will return indexes relative to your view's model. And It is the proxy. So to access data of your model you must map it:

e.g.:

Consider you have a signal on current item change:

```
 connect( p_selectionModel,
    SIGNAL( currentChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &)),
    this,
    SLOT(viewCurrentChanged(const QModelIndex &, const QModelIndex &)));
```

On your slot:

```
viewCurrentChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected)
```

selected will be a QModelIndex of your proxy. You could access to data through

```
selected.data() ..
```

But if your accessig this way:

```
your_model->data( selected, role )
```

Your accessing your model with a proxy index, that will fail.
You should do it this way:

```
your_model->data( proxy_model->mapToSource(selected) , role )
```

( [mapToSource(...)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractproxymodel.html#mapToSource) )

If your working with a QSelection, ( as in selectionChanged(const QItemSelection & selected, const QItemSelection & deselected) signal  ) use

[mapSelectionToSource()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractproxymodel.html#mapSelectionToSource)

To do the reverse path, use:

[QItemSelection  QAbstractProxyModel::mapFromSource(const QModelIndex & sourceIndex) const](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractproxymodel.html#mapFromSource)
[QItemSelection QAbstractProxyModel::mapSelectionFromSource(const QItemSelection & sourceSelection)](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qabstractproxymodel.html#mapSelectionFromSource)

And dont set the selection model on that button slot! It makes no sense. It will be always the same.

Comment: It is so difficult to understand. I still can not do this.